# Slim PHP Hook for after route, before render

Tags: php, routes, slim

Currently I'm trying to implement this behavior:

1. I make several routers
2. Inside a router, I change an environment variable
3. That environment variable is accessible on `before.dispatch`

Basically, I want to be able to do this:

```
$app->get('(/)', function() use ($app, $env) {
    $env['title'] = 'My page title';
    $app->render('index.tpl', array(
        'test' => 'Test!!!',
    ));
});
```

While I also have this:

```
$app->hook('slim.before.dispatch', function () use ($app, $env) {
    $app->view()->appendData(array(
        'env' => $env
    ));
    if (!isset($env['partial']) || $env['partial'] != true)
        $app->render('header.tpl');
});
```

Problem is, the $env['title'] is only available in `index.tpl`, and not `header.tpl`, I'm assuming because in `before.dispatch`, I don't apply the route yet.

How can I achieve this behavior without having to `applyHook()` at every route I need to change header template variables for?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've got a scope issue, and the way you're attempting to get a variable from your route into the variable in your hook simply isn't going to work.

Instead, you should be adding `$env` to view via the `$app->render()` call in your route, like so:

```
$app->render('index.tpl', array(
    'test' => 'Test!!!',
    'env' => $env,
));
```

When you do that, the data in `$env` will be available in any of the `slim.after` hooks.

**IMPORTANT**: Since you're appending `'env'` to the view data in your hook, I highly recommend naming your page title array key `title`, or else the env data you've appended in the `render` method will be overwritten.  The new render arguments would look like:

```
$app->render('index.tpl', array(
    'test' => 'Test!!!',
    'title' => 'My page title',
));
```

Your template engine should now be able to access the `title` in both `header.tpl` and `index.tpl`.

Comment: The index isn't the issue - it's working. I want to update the title via my routes, but that title will need to show up on a render that is displayed before the route is rendered - where I render header.tpl. Problem is the render for the header is with the env before it gets changed. I'm thinking about extending slim with queued rendering but it is harder than I expected.

Comment: If you want to set the title via a route, but stop before ever making it to the route, you won't ever be able to get the title. My point is if you write your hook for one of the `slim.after` hooks, then you'll have access to view data you've set in your route.

Comment: Then what is the convention - how does one achieve automatically adding layout (header/footer) to page renders while being able to modify things in the header from the route?

Comment: That's the responsibility of your view.  Based on the .tpl extension, I'm guessing you're using Smarty?  If so, see their {include} documentation: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.tpl.  Also see the Slim-Views: https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Views